# How to autoplay any iframe video if it is in the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

there developers
I'm actually in a bit of a problem I'm trying to make stuff something like if the iframe is in the viewport then video will autoplay

**Condition**

1. Iframe is in viewport then video will play
2. iframe video get paused if it is not in the viewport
3. iframe video get paused if any modal open

```js
    function playvideo(iframe) {
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(
        '{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}',
        '*'
      )
    }
    
    function pausevideo(iframe) {
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(
        '{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}',
        '*'
      )
    }
    let observeroptions = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: 1.0
    };
    
    let callback = (entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          playvideo(entry.target)
        } else {
          // pausevideo(entry.target);
          observer.unobserve(entry.target)
        }
      })
    }
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, observeroptions);
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      $('iframe').each(function (e) {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
          observer.observe($(this)[0])
        }
      })
    })
```

This is my website link

https://letscodeon.me/research.php?category=videos

**Problem**
The problem is that video is getting paused when the page reload it is not autoplaying when it is in viewport
If i play one video then autoplay is working
if i'm opening a modal then back video is not getting paused

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a scroll function and why you take the observer off an element when it goes out of the viewport. Is there a reason for not using just observers and letting them tell you when the video is in the viewport or out of it?

Comment: Observer is telling the as it work async so, yeah when the video is out of viewport then then the condtion is satisfying

Right now the major issue of mine is When the page load the video is not playing when it is in viewport once i click on any video then the funciton working fine

Comment: Coud  you put up a working snippet with say a couple of videos as I can't get your playvideo function to work.

Comment: Okay I'll check up something and make a jsfiddle then will provide you the link okay